# Notification on paste

Tags: mfc

I want to change the value of column # 1 when ever there is a change in the value of column#3 of CListCtrl.
I used LVN_ENDLABELEDIT to do the same and my code seems to work fine whenever user change value of column#3 and press enter.
But this is not working in case user paste values in this ( Ctlr + V). Any Suggestion?

Code

```
ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ENDLABELEDIT, IDC_PAGEITEMS_LIST, &CClassList::OnListItemEndEditLabel)

void CClassList::OnListItemEndEditLabel(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    NMLVDISPINFO *pDispInfo = reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(pNMHDR);
    if(pDispInfo->item.iSubItem == 5)
    {
        CString days = m_List.GetItemText(pDispInfo->item.iItem, pDispInfo->item.iSubItem);
        COleDateTime date =  COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime() + COleDateTimeSpan(_ttoi(days),0,0,0);
        m_List.SetItemText(pDispInfo->item.iItem , 4, date.Format(VAR_DATEVALUEONLY));

    }else if(pDispInfo->item.iSubItem == 4)
    {
        CString dateStr = m_List.GetItemText(pDispInfo->item.iItem, pDispInfo->item.iSubItem);
        COleDateTime date; date.ParseDateTime(dateStr);
        CString DaysToDeliver;
        DaysToDeliver.Format( L"%d", ( date - COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime() ).GetDays() +1 ) ;
        m_List.SetItemText(pDispInfo->item.iItem , 5, DaysToDeliver);

    }
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us code. Even the user uses Ctrl+V you must receive LVN_ENDLABELEDIT when the inplace edit ends.

Comment: After pressing [Ctrl] + V the user still has to hit [Enter] for the notification to get fired. If it doesn't I'm sure there's some `PreTranslateMessage` hackery at work.

Comment: yes if user press enter I get the notification but I can't force the user to press enter always.